# Using the custom enum attributes values

Tags: android

In my application I'm using the following custom attribute for a custom view:

```
<attr name="direction">
    <enum name="up" value="1" />
    <enum name="down" value="2" />
</attr>
```

The thing is that in my custom view I must compare the current direction with the possible
ones. Is there a way to access the values for the up & down attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon this [AttributeSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html) class . It should help you to retrieve data from compiled XML files.